# iOS Segmented Control does not appear in Interface Builder (or in the app)

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, customization, uisegmentedcontrol

So there is this main UIViewController, which has a Container View. Inside it lives a Table View with custom UITableViewCells. In some cells, I'm dragging and dropping a Segmented Control.

The problem: the Segmented Control keeps invisible in the Interface Builder and / or in the app (running in the devices).

This is not a z-order issue, I double checked.

I wonder if I'm doing something that is not allowed (a Segmented Control inside a UITableViewCell).

However: it works just fine for, say, that UISwitch over there. Or a UISlider. But the Segmented Control...

[Here is a better version of the image below.](http://cl.ly/image/2h0O0W293h0Q)

---

[image: Segmented Control Issue]

Comment: It generally won't behave in this way, which version on Xcode you are using? Are you sure you have defined enough height for table view cell to accommodate all your subviews?

Comment: It's very weird indeed. My Xcode version is 5.1.1. The cell has 44 points height while the segmented control has 28 (and it's vertically centralised).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question since others may have the same issue: my solution was to recreate that View Controller. That's right, I deleted it and started a new one from scratch. I still don't know what happened.

I submitted a Technical Support Incident (TSI) to Apple, will update if I get anything back.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say if it's the same issue for you, but I had my tint colour set to white.